# Ubuntu Software center in Ubuntu 13.04 crashes when opened

Tags: software-center

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 with Gnome 3.8.1.When I try to open Ubuntu Software center, it simply crashes.

Somebody please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Do you receive any accompanying error message?
Also, if you attempt to use `apt-get` do you receive any error messages?

Comment: Maybe you could try, `sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 6):

Run this command in terminal. It will re-install the software-center and reset your settings.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

But for reconfigure a program you can use:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure software-center --force
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had software-center crash on launch after the Ubuntu 13.04 upgrade. It turned out to be in import error in the ubuntu-sso-login. I resolved it by reinstalling the oauthlib python package

```
sudo pip install --upgrade oauthlib
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same proble which I solved by deleting /home/user/.cache/software-center folder.

Comment: This worked for me, unlike the other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it can happen when you add a new but mismatched source. It should be written in the error message then. If it is the problem, remove the source line.