# Ubuntu Software Center Not Working!

Tags: networking, software-center

I really new to Linux. I have no idea how to fix this problem myself. I have installed the newest version i believe. Ubuntu 14.04.1. When ever i launch the Software app, it loads for 30sec then force quits by itself. I'm really lost. I really want to install steam so i can play some CPU games on this laptop.

Comment: I feel like software-center did not install. i'm getting these messages. software-center: no process found. when i try to kill the software or config it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall Software center using

`sudo apt-get update && apt-get install --reinstall software-center`.

In some cases like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/315742/146791) 
deleting `~/.cache/software-center` also worked.

Comment: ok, i have no idea how to uninstall apps, can you please explain exactly how to do it.

Comment: They just did. Go ahead and type "Control-Alt-T" and it will open a terminal window. Then you can type the command above. This will reinstall the software center.

Comment: ok seems like theres activity on the terminal. after i put in my sudo password. The only problem now, is its stuck on the 100% [waiting for headers], and i cant type in anything. Should i just exit out, or wait for it? Seems frozen.

Comment: It is updating you software list(apt-get update). It will not take much time.