# Ubuntu 15.10 Software Center not starting

Tags: software-center, 15.10

I have been using Ubuntu from time to time but not an expert. I have been looking for a fix to this problem to no avail. The Ubuntu Software Center was working fine and now suddenly it is not starting up. Initially I thought it had something to do with installing the Synaptic package manager so I removed it and tried reinstalling software center as mentioned in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524832/ubuntu-software-center-not-working). It did not work.

Trying to run `software-center` in terminal yielded the following:

```
2016-01-30 12:36:02,351 - softwarecenter.backend.zeitgeist_logger - WARNING - Support for Zeitgeist disabled
2016-01-30 12:36:02,415 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2016-01-30 12:36:02,474 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py', 410, '_introspect_error_handler')'
2016-01-30 12:36:02,474 - dbus.proxies - ERROR - Introspect error on com.ubuntu.sso:/com/ubuntu/sso/credentials: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process com.ubuntu.sso exited with status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 338, in __init__
    self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/appmanager.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.oauth_token = helper.find_oauth_token_sync()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/ubuntusso.py", line 141, in find_oauth_token_sync
    sso.find_credentials()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/login_impl/login_sso.py", line 74, in find_credentials
    self.proxy.find_credentials(self.appname, self._get_params())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process com.ubuntu.sso exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a problem with the symbolic link. An answer provided [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1085425) helped.

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope
$ ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/interface
```